# Titanium android reloading when orientation was changed

Tags: android, titanium, orientation, appcelerator

I'm currently developing Android App using Titanium Appcelerator. When I load my application it works fine, but when I changed my device orientation from portrait to landscape or vice verse the window reloaded. How can I fixed my app to set no reload when orientation was changed?

Here's my tiapp.xml:

```
   <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <tool-api-level>17</tool-api-level>
    <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal"
        android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.0.2">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Action">
            <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

and in my app.js:

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();
var myWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: "My Window",
    url: "window/myWindow.js"
});

var myTab = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    window: myWindow,
});

tabGroup.addTab(myTab);
tabGroup.open();
```

and here's my window(myWindow.js):

```
var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
currentWin.addEventListener('open', function() {
     alert('Hello World');
});
```

The alert "Hello World" has been loaded upon changing of device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer just change android activity of your tiapp.xml

```
 <activity android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"/>
```